# What is the X matrix supposed to look like for a regression model that uses cell means coding?

Tags: regression, categorical-encoding

A study wants to test the effectiveness of three types of drug on a person's weight. The regression model uses cell means coding with no intercept, and one categorical independent variable with 0-1 indicator dummy variable for each category. What should the X matrix look like? I'm guessing its dimension is n x 3, where n is the number of participants for the study.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the dimension of the X matrix will be $ n \times 3$. It will look like:

```
| 1 0 0 |
| 1 0 0 |
...
| 1 0 0 |
| 0 1 0 |
| 0 1 0 |
...
| 0 1 0 |
| 0 0 1 |
| 0 0 1 |
...
| 0 0 1 |
```